# Cryptic Crossword: Pokemon Korean Pop Star avoids object thrown at his head! (7)

Tags: cryptic-clues

Shouldn't be too hard:

Pokemon Korean Pop Star avoids object thrown at his head!  (7)

Comment: Nice one! I'd improve the surface reading though, and change "avoids" to match "duck" (since verbs' tense and conjugation should match). Maybe something like "Pokemon star from Korea, get out of the way!"

Comment: (Probably shouldn't have partial answer in comment....)  But a good idea though.

Comment: that one is perhaps a bit too easy I think .... I just read it in Hot Questions and got it right away.  I'd be disappointed in a cryptic crossword that had more than a few clues quite that simple; it's almost a "straight" crossword clue

Comment: I don't understand why there is `(7)` though.

Comment: @Lafexlos It's the number of letters in the answer

Comment: Deusovi: Alternatively, "to avoid" instead of "avoids" would solve that problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Perhaps it's:

> Psyduck?
>  Korean pop star = [Psy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psy)
>  avoids object thrown at his head = [duck](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/duck) (verb),
>  so Psy + duck = [Psyduck, a Pokémon](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Psyduck_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29).

Comment: Yep, easy one!  Good job!

Comment: @DooplissForce It's actually `his head` not `his dead`.

Comment: @AJ Ah, my bad!

Comment: Completely ignores "at his head"  But this could be questioner's error.  
"Pokemon Korean Pop Star avoids thrown object " would be sufficient.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore if thrown at foot or side, could be 'hop' or 'swerves'.